# How to change the color of the calendar icon of the TextField date-picker? In Material-UI React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How to change color icon date-picker? [IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mWUl.png)
I've already gone through a lot of options, but still can't find how to change the color of the icon. With the help of '.MuiSelect-icon' it was possible to change the color of the TextFiled select ..

```
const TextField2 = withStyles({
root: {
    '& .MuiInput-underline:after': {
        borderBottomColor: '#ffffff',
    },
    "& .MuiSelect-icon": {
        color: "#ffffff"
    },
    "& .MuiInput-icon": {
        color: "#ffffff"
    },
},})(TextField);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  filter: invert(24%) sepia(85%) saturate(7299%) hue-rotate(356deg)
    brightness(107%) contrast(117%);
}
```

[image: Edit unruffled-euclid-eumc0]

Use [CSS filter generator](https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp) to convert from black to target hex color using `filter` property